# React - unable to call props value inside a usecallback function

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, react-functional-component

```
 import React,{useEffect,useCallBack} from 'react';

 ReactfunctionalComponent = ({className, DropDownValue, ...rest}) => {

     console.log(DropDownValue); //will log the value

     const getCustomers = useCallback(async ()=> {
         console.log(DropDownValue) // will not log the value (undefined)
     };
     
     useEffect(() => {
         console.log(DropDownvalue) // will not log the value (undefined)

         getCustomers();

     },[getCustomers]);

 return (
  <ListView/>
)
```

}

### Unable to pass the DropDwonValue inside callback function

The value can be accessed across all the scope but just not inside the callback function, suggest to me if I'm using the method wrong or any alternative usage is there to use dropdown value.

DropdownValue comes from another component.

please do suggest if you know how to trigger a function on the component render, basically, I need to make an API call when the dropdown value comes in.

Comment: Do post your whole code.

Comment: useCallback should always be called with a dependencies array, otherwise it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the first time the component renders, `DropDownValue` is `undefined`. That's the value the callbacks close over. Since you are not telling React that the callbacks depend on `DropDownValue`, the callbacks are not going to be recreated when the value changes.

Add `DropDownValue` as a dependency:

```
const getCustomers = useCallback(async() => {
    console.log(DropDownValue);
}, [DropDownValue]);
```

> basically, I need to make an API call when the dropdown value comes in.

That's what `useEffect` allows you to do. You just need to specify the value as a dependency, as described in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect). The API is the same as for `useCallback`:

```
useEffect(async() => {
    console.log(DropDownValue);
}, [DropDownValue]);
```

Comment: I think this might work I'll try and let you all know, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
**You can do it in two ways:-**

//One way
const getCustomers = useCallback(async() => {
            console.log(DropDownValue);
        }, [DropDownValue]);
    
    useEffect(async() => {
       getCustomers();
    }, [getCustomers]);
    
        //Another

    const getCustomers = useCallback(async(DropDownValue) => {
        console.log(DropDownValue);
    }, []);

    useEffect(async() => {
           getCustomers(DropDownValue);
        }, [getCustomers,DropDownValue]);
```

Comment: Thank you but you won't get the prop inside useEffect, I have pointed that out